# How to decompile a obfuscated mach-o dylib?

Tags: deobfuscation, mach-o

I am trying to decompile a dylib called libConfigurer64.dylib, which is loaded from the environment variable "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES"

I want to analyze what it really does, so I dragged it in to IDA, and found that it exported "_sub_06adf","_sub_06bdf","InitFunc_0"

In _sub_06adf:

```
db 'VfhT2zwxQpLeHRL6j4Oe4mrsmrjEAW',0
align 10h
```

In _sub_06bdf

```
db '(c) 2014 - Cryptic Apps SARL - Disassembling not allowed.',0
db    0
db    0
db    0
db    0
```

They aren't correct asm code! And I have no clue what tool obfuscated this file.
And I'm also curious about how can this dylib overwrite exisiting functions?

Note: I've read https://alexomara.com/blog/a-silly-anti-disassembly-trick/, however this dylib isn't that trick, but is really obfuscated XD

Comment: did u do anything related to this file ? I'm working on reversing it but it's really heavily obfuscated.

Comment: @Coldzer0 Nope. I gave up at last.... This file is really hard to deobfuscate!